# Cannot get www cname to work in apache and bind

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, bind

On Cent OS 6, apache 2.2, Bind 9.7.3
I cannot get my domains to load with www cname. If I type example.com it loads fine, but www.example.com loads my main apache directory from /var/www/html

This is what I have in httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/_domains/example.com"
ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/_domains/example2.com"
ServerName example2.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName 94.00.00.00
</VirtualHost>
```

And a zone file for example.com looks like this:

```
$ttl 38400
example.com.    IN  SOA example.com. webmaster.example.com. (
            1326544028
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )

example.com.          IN NS   ns1.example.com.
example.com.          IN NS   ns2.example.com.
ns1.example.com.               IN A    94.00.00.00
ns2.example.com.               IN A    94.00.00.00
example.com.          IN A    94.00.00.00
mail.example.com.             IN A    94.00.00.00
www.example.com.              IN CNAME        example.com.
example.com.          IN MX  10 mail.example.com.
```

Any thoughts on why www.example.com would load the default html directory `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www/html/_domains/example.com` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are not including www into your Virtualhost. So Apache does not know what you are talking about. So you need to add a ServerAlias as well :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/_domains/example.com"
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ah, `ServerAlias` , of course :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the lines:

```
ServerAlias www.example.com

ServerAlias www.example2.com
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to the `ServerAlias` directive. So, your virutal host defintion should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/_domains/example.com"
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

For more info, you can [see](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html).